# Optimize jquery Selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a jQuery selector designed to retrieve all required fields that are not set as read-only and not disabled.

To do so I used the following selector (div = div containing my controls)

```
div.find(':input[required]:not([readonly]):not([disabled])')
```

The find method has poor performance. Is there a way to optimize this selector?

Comment: "*The find method has poor performance*" - does it?

Comment: Is this doing any better:     

`$("#yourdiv input[required]:not(:disabled):not([readonly])")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
div.find('input:required:not(:readonly, :disabled)')
```

However if an HTML input is readonly it should never be required.